# Dynamically set Mousetrap.bind() key combinations from an object

Tags: javascript, mousetrap

I'm getting back data from our backend that contains information about keyboard shortcuts. This is a dumbed down version of what I will receive:

```
    { code: "r", message: "test R" },
    { code: "s", message: "test S" },
    { code: "c", message: "test C"}
```

The 'Code' specifies which key will activate the keyboard shortcut, and the message is what will be pasted in an input box.

I am using the [Mousetrap](https://craig.is/killing/mice) library, which allows me to write functions like so:

```
Mousetrap.bind('shift+^+r', function () {
    alert("test");
});
```

My question is: is there a way to write these functions at runtime based on the data brought back? So for every item in the JSON object, a function will be needed to handle the shortcut.

I've tried this:

```
    var html = document.getElementById("shortcuts").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("shortcuts").innerHTML = html + "<script> Mousetrap.bind('shift+^+r', function () { alert('test) })); <\/script>"
```

I don't know if this is good practice, as I am still quite new to JS, but this was the only thing I could come up with. It doesnt work though.

Comment: No, don't "write a function". Don't create a `<script>` element. Just call that `Mousetrap.bind` method with a string derived from your runtime data.

Comment: You might want to accept AbanaClara's answer, which is just what I would've written

Comment: @Bergi Upon giving that comment more thought, I was thinking how I would then call that for each item in the array. As there would need to be multiple variables; one for each item.

Comment: Just loop over the array and call `bindKey` with each item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. Sounds easy enough. Just create a separate function accepting an object, getting both the `code` and `message` properties and calling `Mousetrap.bind(str, func)` on runtime

```
function bindKey(input){
    const code = input.code;
    const message = input.message;

    const bindStr = "shift+^+" + code; //idk if you need shift here but modify as needed

    Mousetrap.bind(bindStr, function(){
          alert(message);
    });
}
```

Use via

```
bindKey({code: "r", message: "test R"});
bindKey({code: "c", message: "test C"});
bindKey({code: "d", message: "test D"});
```

If you have an array of objects, just loop through them and call `bindKey()`

```
myArray.forEach(bindKey);
// or
for (const i of myArray) bindKey(i);
```

No need to write a script element. Just write the function and call it on runtime. Why you need to render a script tag is beyond me.

---

Test below

```js
function bindKey(input){
   const code = input.code;
   const message = input.message;

   const bindStr = "shift+^+" + code; //idk if you need shift here but modify as needed
    
    Mousetrap.bind(bindStr, function(){
          console.log(message);
    });
}
    
bindKey({code: "r", message: "test R"});
bindKey({code: "c", message: "test C"});
bindKey({code: "d", message: "test D"});
```

```html
<script src="https://craig.global.ssl.fastly.net/js/mousetrap/mousetrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Plastic I did. `document.write` and creating functions from `<script>` elements is a horrible practice. It doesn't even solve OPs problem of deriving the code dynamically from the json data.

Comment: @Bergi, you are totally right, and i delete my answer, I was just pointing that in the way he tried to append the script to the page it will never run.
By the way, you should always try to argue a downvote.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Why I need to render a script tag is beyond me too, it was just the first thing that came to mind, so thanks for teaching me that it's bad practice.

Comment: I don't seem to able to get this working. When using bindKey for each of the items in the array, thats the only time the method is called. When actually pressing the shortcuts, nothing happens.

Comment: @Mahogany I mistyped the string format for the Mousetrap library. Fixed and included a working snippet

Comment: Great, thats working now. @shrys's answer is working too. Which would you recommend using?

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through all the objects, upon binding the key with `code` from each object you can search through the array and pick the element to display the message. Modest implementation:

```js
var data = [{code:"r",message:"test R"},{code:"s",message:"test S"},{code:"c",message:"test C"}];

//use forEach to go through each item in data
data.forEach(key => {
  //call MouseTrap bind on key.code, key is one of the element in data
  Mousetrap.bind('shift+^+' + key.code, (e) => {
    //e is the event variable from the keystroke
    
    //data.find will find the element which has the key value(e.key) from the event
    //converting into lowercase because data is in lowercase too
    var element = data.find(d => {
      //check if code of the element matches e.key
      if (d.code == e.key.toLowerCase()) return d;
    });
    //log element.message
    console.log(element.message);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://craig.global.ssl.fastly.net/js/mousetrap/mousetrap.min.js"></script>
```

---

Suggestion from [@Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi), [@AZ_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9381809/az):

```js
var data = [{code:"r",message:"test R"},{code:"s",message:"test S"},{code:"c",message:"test C"}];

data.forEach(({code, message}) => Mousetrap.bind(`shift+^+${code}`, () => console.log(message)));
```

```html
<script src="https://craig.global.ssl.fastly.net/js/mousetrap/mousetrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow, this is working brilliantly. Could you possible explain how this is working for a novice?

Comment: You'll want to use `find`, not `filter`, and you'll want to return a boolean from the callback. But why search the `data` at all? You already have the object with the `.message` in the `key` variable.

Comment: @shrys Perfect, thank you. Currently yours is working the best, will leave this for a few hours and then accept an answer.

Comment: @Mahogany kewl kewl

Comment: As @Bergi said what's the point of researching the element from array, only `data.forEach(({code, message}) => Mousetrap.bind(\`shift+^+${code}\`, () => console.log(message)))` is enough